# Create an Excel Table with Some Columns from Another Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table called HeRaw.

I opened a new sheet called Sheet1.

I set Sheet1's A1 formula to "=HeRaw[[#All],[IP]]". So now column A mirrors HeRaw's IP column.

Let's, for the fun of it, count the number of chars in the IP. So in B1, I set the value to 'NumChars, ' and B2 to "=LEN(A2)". I double-click the little point at the bottom right of B2, and Excel extends the formula to all the B-Cells with values at their corresponding A cells.

Now, I want to create a table composed of the filled cells in AB, meaning that the first column will be HeRaw's IP column, and the second column will be the number of chars in the first column.

However, selecting A1:B2 and clicking Control-T shows a warning: "Formulas or rich data types in the header row will be removed and converted to static text. Do you wish to continue?" Continuing, I get a SPILL for the first column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide information how your table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

There are nuances to the way tables and dynamic arrays work.  A table is still part of a defined data structure even when its individual cells may be empty.  Thus, to the dynamic array engine, the cells inside of a table appear to be "off limits"--they are already "owned" by the table's object properties.

So the short answer is that excel does not support dynamic arrays appearing within a table.